# How can i send the output of an NAudio WaveMixerStream32 to an ApiController FileStreamResult

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, naudio

Does anyone have any idea how you would send the output of WaveMixerStream32 to a FileStreamResult? I want to process some audio but then access it in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

In NAudio all Wav classes derive from WavStream class, and WavStream class derives from System.IO.Stream.

Here is a sample:

```
var inFile = @"c:\test.wav";
var inFileFormat = WaveFormat.CreateALawFormat(8000,1);

using (var inStream = File.OpenRead(inFile))
using (var reader = new RawSourceWaveStream(inStream, inFileFormat))
{
    using (var waveMixerStream = new WaveMixerStream32(new List<WaveStream>() { reader }, true))
    {
        using (var fsResult = new FileStreamResult(waveMixerStream, "audio/wav"))
        {
            /* any custom here */
        }
    }
}
```

[RawSourceWaveStream](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/RawSourceWaveStream.md)

Also needs to modify the dispose method from WaveMixerStream32 class, as following:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            /* no need to dispose each inputStream,
               let all inputStreams released by GC

            /* lock (inputsLock)
            {
                foreach (WaveStream inputStream in inputStreams)
                {
                    inputStream.Dispose();
                }
            } */
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, "WaveMixerStream32 was not disposed");
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

[WaveMixerStream32.cs](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/WaveStreams/WaveMixerStream32.cs)

Hope this helps.